# Is it dangerous to automatically encode things like space, tab, indent, etc... before saving to php?

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, encoding, code-injection

I want the ability to copy a text, whether it is a list, a paragraph with an indent, spaces, breaks and enter it into the database "pre-formatted."

for example this is tab:

I have started to do this with javascript, automatically detecting key strokes and getting the character encoding and concatenating each character to make a string.

I'm a little rusty, I haven't used these functions in a while, pretty sure I have to pass keynum through

```
function charbank(){
this.value = "";
}

var charcount = new charbank3();

function insertchar(fnc){
fnc.value = charcount.value + String.fromCharCode(keynum);
}

function myKeyPress(e){
var keynum;

if(window.event){ // IE                 
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }else
                if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                  
                    keynum = e.which;
                 }
            updatecount(count);
            // insertchar(keynum);
        }
```

Comment: Doing this in JS is not dangerous, but not doing a second check in PHP after that **is** dangerous, because anyone with bad intentions can bypass your javascript check. Or they can just have JS disabled in their browser.

Comment: So I would do like a htmspecialchars as the last filter when outputting from php?